# What is the significance of the scene of Soul Stone Pocket Dimension with young Gamora?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos snaps his fingers and causes the Snapocalypse.

Next scene is Thanos and a young Gamora within an odd place, devoid of many features beyond an Asian style gazebo or similar.

What is the significance of this scene?  Much speculation before *Endgame* was that this was where all the snapped souls went, but after *Endgame*, this is unclear.

Comment: Similar question on SFF: [Red lake with gate, where these two characters meet at the end of Infinity War](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186733/98028), with a directors' interview

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a place those who use the stones enter after use. Collecting the stones costs the user a lot and the place seems to be a place where the user can face the cost of what they've done.

As we now know there were plans to show Tony in this place with his daughter but the scene was cut, it was likely the scene of Thanos and Gamora was initially going to mirror that of Tony and a teenage Morgan. Young Gamora doesn't accept what Thanos did, whereas details from the cut scene between Tony and Morgan reveal that Morgan understands what Tony did and gives him the peace that allows him to pass away.